# How can i get the value of an object inside of array and put on the DOM but each time that i push the button change it to the next object

Tags: javascript

i'll want to do that the value of an object inside of array displays in the DOM and each time that i push the button change to the next object with differents valors and change the DOM.

For more context about how i want it to work, i did the interface with the first object:  https://learnkev.pages.dev/

i try to do a personal vocabulary to improve my english:)

code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

const wordy = document.querySelector('#word');
const palabraHTML = document.querySelector('#palabra');
const sentence = document.querySelector('#sen')
const oracion = document.querySelector('#oracion')
const btnReload = document.querySelector('#button');

btnReload.addEventListener('click', reload);

function reload () {

        const conjunto = words.map((word) => word.word);
        const conjunto2 = words.map((word) => word.palabra);
        const conjunto3 = words.map((word) => word.sentence);
        const conjunto4 = words.map((word) => word.oracion);

        wordy.textContent = conjunto[0]
        palabraHTML.textContent = conjunto2[0]
        sentence.textContent = conjunto3[0]
        oracion.textContent = conjunto4[0]


}




const words = [

{
    word: "the",
        palabra: "El / Los",sentence: "The sun is up",
        oracion: "El sol ha salido"
},
{
    word: "be",palabra: "Ser / Estar",sentence: "Don't be sad",
        oracion: "No estes trsite"
},
{
        word: 'as',palabra: 'como (adv.)',sentence: 'He used me as a guinea pig',
        oracion: 'Me utilizó como conejillo de indias'
},
{
        word: 'will', palabra: '(futuro), voluntad', sentence: 'Will she come?',
        oracion: '¿Vendrá? (Ella)'
}

];


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply store the index state in a variable and increment it each time you call reload:

```js
const words = [ // you must define this before using it
  {
    word: "the",
    palabra: "El / Los",
    sentence: "The sun is up",
    oracion: "El sol ha salido"
  },
  {
    word: "be",
    palabra: "Ser / Estar",
    sentence: "Don't be sad",
    oracion: "No estes trsite"
  },
  {
    word: 'as',
    palabra: 'como (adv.)',
    sentence: 'He used me as a guinea pig',
    oracion: 'Me utilizó como conejillo de indias'
  },
  {
    word: 'will',
    palabra: '(futuro), voluntad',
    sentence: 'Will she come?',
    oracion: '¿Vendrá? (Ella)'
  }

];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const wordy = document.getElementById('word'); // prefer getElementById to find an node by id selector.
  const palabraHTML = document.getElementById('palabra');
  const sentence = document.getElementById('sen')
  const oracion = document.getElementById('oracion')
  const btnReload = document.getElementById('button');

  btnReload.addEventListener('click', reload);

  let index = 0;

  function updateIndex() {
    index = index === words.length - 1 ?
      0 :
      index + 1;
  }

  // you don't have to define those variables each time you call reload, you can define them once outside of the function.
  const conjunto = words.map((word) => word.word);
  const conjunto2 = words.map((word) => word.palabra);
  const conjunto3 = words.map((word) => word.sentence);
  const conjunto4 = words.map((word) => word.oracion);

  function reload() {
    wordy.textContent = conjunto[index]
    palabraHTML.textContent = conjunto2[index]
    sentence.textContent = conjunto3[index]
    oracion.textContent = conjunto4[index]

    updateIndex();
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="word">-</div>
<div id="palabra">-</div>
<div id="sen">-</div>
<div id="oracion">-</div>
<button id="button">Reload</button>
```